# Clarification needed regarding ServerSocket

Tags: java, android

I have a Thread which listens for connection, like this:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5288);
trans = server.accept();
```

This is all good, since no interface is defined, this will listen on all interfaces, which is what I want/need.

However on a different thread I might bring up another network interface. I couldn't find it in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket(int)) what will happen in this case. Will the above created listener also listen on the newly added interface or do I need to recreate the listener?

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yes it will. Technically you are accepting from *any* interface, including future ones, rather than *all* interfaces as they existed when you bound the socket.

Comment: Thanks @user207421 thats what I thought so, I just experienced some cases where my client won't connect and I had no errors so I was double checking everything. Could you please put it in an answer so I can accept it?